# Try method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to collect elements from an array like below

```
@arr.collect(&:title)
```

But sometimes the @arr can have some values and it throws undefined method error. So using `try` as below.

So how can i handle it with `try` method?

Comment: You can add a check for empty @arr
Like:
     @arr.collect(&:title) if @arr.present?

Comment: @user3078630 @arr cant be blank. it can have some values. But it returns undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Comment: what is your ruby version?

Comment: @rubyist that sounds suspicious. Why does `@arr` contain objects that do respond to `title` and others that don't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the way below:

```
@arr.collect {|e| e.respond_to?(:title) ? e.title : nil }
```

Or if your Ruby version > 2.3.0, safe navigation operator can be used instead of Rails `try`:

```
@arr.collect { |e| e&.title }
```